# How can i access this element using selenium in python?

Tags: python

```html
<div class="field input">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required="">
          <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
</div>
```

I am trying

```
password = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_type("password")
)
```

Comment: What is the website that you are trying to find this element on?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']") should work